# Change content on the "Open in browser" page after sending the mail

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template

Is it possible to change content on the "Open in browser" page after sending the newsletter mail by salesforce marketing cloud? I would like to do it in a way the link will continue to work but targeting the correct text.

Comment: You mean you want to change the text? Like translation?

Comment: Exactly! But only on the "Open in browser" page. The email is kept (I was send already)

Comment: If you sent the email already, the only way of changing the text in it via Data Extensions if you retrieve it from a Data Extension. In other words, you cannot change any content in Marketing Cloud after you sent the email unless you use Data Extensions to populate your data. When you change the Data Extension, online version of your email also is changed. You can change the link via job ID in tracking section but not the text you show.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course change to "Open in Browser" Page of E-Mails afterwards. But for that you have to create AMPScript Logic that has LookUps on DataExtensions when the _messagecontext is "VAWP" (View as WebPage).

Inside the messagecontext you have only some fields you can use to get other data. These are some personalization strings like jobid batchid subscriberkey subscriberid and emailaddress and stuff like this.

Inside your mail your content blocks then must know how to behave in which kind of _messagecontext. When they are viewed normally (like in an email) they behave that way and if they are viewed in VAWP they behave that way. This includes that your email has AMPScripts that place content with content functions like ContentBlockByKey /ID / Name ... or the same for images. For normal text you would just code basic amp with html in code snippet blocks or something like that.

For the personalization strings that are available in vawp watch [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5)

Inside your mail you then code something like this:

```
%%[
    set @JobID = AttributeValue("JobID")
    set @SubscriberID = AttributeValue("SubscriberID")
    set @BatchID = AttributeValue("_JobSubscriberBatchID")

    if _MessageContext == "VAWP" then
        set @SomeField = Lookup("Sendlog",SomeField,"SubID",@SubscriberID,"JobID",@JobID,"BatchID",@BatchID)
    else 
        set @SomeField = AttributeValue(SomeField)
    endif 
]%%
```

Of course you can enchance the logic when you only want to edit the page after a certain amount of time if you bring the logic inside the ampscript and the VAWP context.